# Show that the $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac n{n+1} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta, infinity

Show that the $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac n{n+1} = 1$ using the limit definition.

So far I have:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \ge 0$ such that,

$|a_n-L|< \varepsilon$, for all $n \ge N$.

$\left|\frac n{n+1} -1\right| < \varepsilon$. I have ended up with $\left|\frac 1{n+1} \right|  \le \frac n n = 1$

(which is $< \varepsilon$, for all $n$)

I know there needs to be an n at the end, so for all $n >$ something $\varepsilon$. I am not sure what to do after $n/n$, or is that enough to show the limit of the sequence $= 1$.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing the point.   You want $|f(n) - L|<\epsilon$ to be very very close to $0$.  To shown that it is less than $L=1$ (which is *WAY* bigger than $\epsilon$) is useless.  But just do $|\frac 1{n+1}| < \epsilon \Leftarrow 1 < \epsilon(n+1) \Leftarrow n > \frac {1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}$.   So for any $\epsilon > 0$ then if $n > N =\frac {1-\epsilon}\epsilon \implies |\frac n{n+1} -1| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that for $A,B>0$

$$A<B \iff \frac 1 A > \frac 1 B$$

we have that $\forall \varepsilon>0$

$$\left| \frac1{n+1}\right|<\varepsilon \iff n+1 >\frac1 \varepsilon \iff n>\frac1 \varepsilon  -1$$

then we can take any $N\ge \frac1 \varepsilon  -1$ to comply the definition of limit.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\epsilon > \left|\frac{n}{n+1} - 1\right| = \left|-\frac{1}{n+1}\right| = \frac{1}{n+1} \hspace{10pt} \Longrightarrow \hspace{10pt} n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} -1 
\end{align*}